# Generate distribution given percentile ranks

Tags: r, statistics

I'd like to generate a distribution in R given the following [**score and percentile ranks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile_rank).

```
x <- 1:10
PercRank <- c(1, 7, 12, 23, 41, 62, 73, 80, 92, 99)
```

`PercRank = 1` for example tells that 1% of the data has a `value/score <= 1` (the first value of x). Similarly, `PercRank = 7` tells that 7% of the data has a `value/score <= 2` etc..

I am not aware of how one could find the underlying distribution. I'd be glad if I could get some guidance on how to go about obtaining the `pdf` of the underlying distribution from just this much information.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Arun: The answer you provided is clearly directed to a different question than this. The values you provide do not have a domain of support in the range of 1:10.

Comment: @Arun: Looks more on point for the posted question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile_rank):

> The percentile rank of a score is the percentage of scores in its frequency distribution that are the same or lower than it.

In order to illustrate this, let's create a distribution, say, a `normal distribution`, with `mean=2` and `sd=2`, so that we can test (our code) later.

```
# 1000 samples from normal(2,2)
x1 <- rnorm(1000, mean=2, sd=2)
```

Now, let's take the same `percentile rank` you've mentioned in your post. Let's divide it by 100 so that they represent cumulative probabilities.

```
cum.p <- c(1, 7, 12, 23, 41, 62, 73, 80, 92, 99)/100
```

And what are the values (`scores`) corresponding to these percentiles?

```
# generating values similar to your x.
x <- c(t(quantile(x1, cum.p)))
> x
 [1] -2.1870396 -1.4707273 -1.1535935 -0.8265444 -0.2888791  
         0.2781699  0.5893503  0.8396868  1.4222489  2.1519328
```

This means that 1% of the data is lesser than -2.18. 7% of the data is lesser than -1.47 etc... Now, we have the `x` and `cum.p` (equivalent to your `PercRank`). Let's forget `x1` and the fact that this should be a normal distribution. To find out what distribution it could be, let's get actual probabilities from the cumulative probabilities by using `diff` that takes the difference between nth and (n-1)th element.

```
prob <- c( cum.p[1], diff(cum.p), .01)
> prob
# [1] 0.01 0.06 0.05 0.11 0.18 0.21 0.11 0.07 0.12 0.07 0.01
```

Now, all we have to do is is to generate samples of size, say, 100 (could be any number), for each interval of x `(x[1]:x[2], x[2]:x[3] ...)` and then finally sample from this huge data as many number of points as you need (say, 10000), with probabilities mentioned above.

This can be done by:

```
freq <- 10000 # final output size that we want

# Extreme values beyond x (to sample)
init <- -(abs(min(x)) + 5) 
fin  <- abs(max(x)) + 5

ival <- c(init, x, fin) # generate the sequence to take pairs from
len <- 100 # sequence of each pair

s <- sapply(2:length(ival), function(i) {
    seq(ival[i-1], ival[i], length.out=len)
})
# sample from s, total of 10000 values with probabilities calculated above
out <- sample(s, freq, prob=rep(prob, each=len), replace = T)
```

Now, we have 10000 samples from the distribution. Let's look at how it is. It should resemble a normal distribution with mean = 2 and sd = 2.

```
> hist(out)
```

[image: normal_dist]

```
> c(mean(out), sd(out))
# [1] 1.954834 2.170683
```

It is a normal distribution (from the histogram) with `mean = 1.95` and `sd = 2.17 (~ 2)`.

Note: Some things what I've explained may have been roundabout and/or the code "may/may not" work with some other distributions. The point of this post was just to explain the concept with a simple example.

**Edit:** In an attempt to clarify `@Dwin's` point, I tried the same code with `x = 1:10` corresponding to OP's question, with the same code by replacing the value of x.

```
cum.p <- c(1, 7, 12, 23, 41, 62, 73, 80, 92, 99)/100
prob <- c( cum.p[1], diff(cum.p), .01)
x <- 1:10

freq <- 10000 # final output size that we want

# Extreme values beyond x (to sample)
init <- -(abs(min(x)) + 1) 
fin  <- abs(max(x)) + 1

ival <- c(init, x, fin) # generate the sequence to take pairs from
len <- 100 # sequence of each pair

s <- sapply(2:length(ival), function(i) {
    seq(ival[i-1], ival[i], length.out=len)
})
# sample from s, total of 10000 values with probabilities calculated above
out <- sample(s, freq, prob=rep(prob, each=len), replace = T)

> quantile(out, cum.p) # ~ => x = 1:10
# 1%     7%    12%    23%    41%    62%    73%    80%    92%    99% 
# 0.878  1.989  2.989  4.020  5.010  6.030  7.030  8.020  9.050 10.010 

> hist(out)
```

[image: hist_OPs_data]

Comment: @Arun, is it possible that the minus is wrong in `init <- -(abs(min(x)) + 5)`. For a sample with all positive value, it doesn't seem to work. Couldn't it just be `init <- min(x) - 5`?

Answer (score 1):

i think you want the `ecdf` function, which is mentioned as the inverse of the `quantile` function on the `?quantile` help page..

```
# construct your vector containing the data
PercRank <- c(1, 7, 12, 23, 41, 62, 73, 80, 92, 99)

# construct an empirical cumulative distribution function
# which is really just the `inverse` of `quantile
Fn <- ( ecdf( PercRank ) )
# note that the `ecdf` function returns a function itself.

# calculate what percent of `PercRank` is below these integers..
Fn( 0 )
Fn( 1 )
Fn( 2 )
Fn( 3 )
Fn( 6 )
Fn( 7 )
Fn( 8 )


# re-construct your `x` vector using PercRank
Fn( PercRank ) * 10
```

Comment: @Arun it is a step function.  `x <- seq(0, 100, by=.1); plot(x, Fn(x))`

Comment: Thank you. How would you re-create the underlying data and then plot a histogram?

Comment: @maycobra `hist(Fn(x))` i guess, but i don't entirely understand what you're trying to do.  if Arun's answer didn't solve your problem, then please elaborate on your desired output  :)

Answer (score -1):

This give produces a dataset that would have the features that you specify. If you wanted more "randomness" you could subtract some random number within the range of the percentile span to `rep` result inside the anonymous function:

```
   > mapply( function(x,y) rep(x, each=y), (x),  diff(c(PercRank, 100) ) )
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 2 2 2

[[3]]
 [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3

[[4]]
 [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

[[5]]
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

[[6]]
 [1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6

[[7]]
[1] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

[[8]]
 [1] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8

[[9]]
[1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

[[10]]
[1] 10
```

Comment: Will the downvoter please have the courtesy to explain what is incorrect?