# given percentiles find distribution function python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/30460089/2202107, we can generate CDF of a normal distribution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
Z = np.random.normal(size = N)
# method 1
H,X1 = np.histogram( Z, bins = 10, normed = True )
dx = X1[1] - X1[0]
F1 = np.cumsum(H)*dx
#method 2
X2 = np.sort(Z)
F2 = np.array(range(N))/float(N)

# plt.plot(X1[1:], F1)
plt.plot(X2, F2)
plt.show()
```

**Question**: How do we generate the "original" normal distribution, given only `x (eg X2)` and `y (eg F2)` coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was `plt.plot(x,np.gradient(y))`, but gradient of y was all zero (data points are evenly spaced in y, but not in x) These kind of data is often met in percentile calculations. The key is to get the data evenly space in x and not in y, using interpolation:

```
x=X2
y=F2
num_points=10

xinterp = np.linspace(-2,2,num_points)
yinterp = np.interp(xinterp, x, y)

# for normalizing that sum of all bars equals to 1.0
tot_val=1.0
normalization_factor = tot_val/np.trapz(np.ones(len(xinterp)),yinterp)

plt.bar(xinterp, normalization_factor * np.gradient(yinterp), width=0.2)
plt.show()
```

output looks good to me:

[image]

I put my approach here for examination. Let me know if my logic is flawed.

**One issue is**: when `num_points` is large, the plot looks bad, but it's a issue in discretization, not sure how to avoid it.

Related posts:

- I failed to understand why the answer was so complicated in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6065/131632
- I also didn't understand why my approach was different than [Generate distribution given percentile ranks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547364/generate-distribution-given-percentile-ranks)